# Erro "X-UA-Compatible HTTP header must have the value IE=edge, was IE=Edge,chrome=1"

Tags: php, htaccess, w3c-validador

Eu executei o W3C HTML Validator para verificar se houve algum problema e este é o único erro que eu tenho: //prntscr.com/gj1z22

> "X-UA-Compatible HTTP header must have the value IE=edge, was IE=Edge,chrome=1"

Eu nem tinha nenhum cabeçalho compatível com X-UA. Depois que encontrei este erro, eu fiz minha pesquisa: [1](http://www.validatethis.co.uk/news/fix-bad-value-x-ua-compatible-once-and-for-all/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198594/bad-value-x-ua-compatible-for-attribute-http-equiv-on-element-meta), //www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-solve-http-equiv-validation-error-from-w3c-validator/178466; mudei as configurações do .htaccess e até coloquei algum código PHP em meus cabeçalhos para exibir a meta tag correta, conforme recomendado neste fórum, mas ainda assim, o erro continua

Cabeçalho PHP:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && 
    (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false))
        header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge');
```

.htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        BrowserMatch MSIE ie
        Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge" env=ie
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Por que isso está acontecendo? Tenho em atenção que eu não tinha nenhum cabeçalho desse tipo na primeira vez que recebi esta mensagem. Todas as soluções que encontrei neste fórum não funcionaram.

Comment: Olá João, a resposta lhe ajudou, sobrou alguma duvida em relação a ela?

Answer (score 2):

A mensagem:

> X-UA-Compatible HTTP header must have the value IE=edge, was IE=Edge,chrome=1

Se traduzida diz algo como:

> O cabeçalho HTTP X-UA-Compatible deve conter o valor "IE=edge", mas foi encontrado "IE=Edge,chrome=1"

Ou seja isto pode não ter sido no seu `.htaccess` ou `.php`, e sim na parte HTML, você deve estar usando algo semelhante a isto:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

No entanto o Chormeframe **foi descontinuado** em 2014, conforme o link oficial: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started

> Google Chrome Frame is no longer supported and retired as of February 25, 2014.

Ou seja, o `chrome=1` **não é mais necessário**, basta usar o `IE=edge`, então o HTML deve ficar assim:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

No entanto no se o seu HTML estiver correto então isto quer dizer que você esta usando ou php e/ou htaccess mesmo, procure em todos seus arquivos .php por algo como isto:

```
header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1');
```

e troque por isto:

```
header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge');
```

Se tiver no teu .htaccess algo semelhante:

```
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
```

ou

```
Header add X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
```

E remova o `,chrome=1`:

```
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge"
```

ou

```
Header add X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge"
```

> **Nota:** Não é necessário usar o `header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge');` e nem `Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge" env=ie` junto com `<meta>`, pra resumir, ou você usa o .htaccess, ou você usa o `header()` ou você usa o `<meta>`, os 3 ao mesmo tempo é redundância.

Comment: Então, @Guilherme Nascimento, o pior é que eu não estou usando essa meta tag. Na verdade, não estou usando nada que contenha a string ",chrome=1". Será que isto está vindo do servidor? Obrigado

Comment: @JoãoMarcos manda o link da página que está tentando validar

Comment: aqui está: https://peasc.educative.com.br/

Comment: @JoãoMarcos O problema é um header, https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2noj.png, também veja que editei a pergunta, siga as dicas que deve resolver o problema ;)

Comment: Cara, eu juro pra você que não tem ",chrome=1" em nenhum dos meus arquivos. Antes de ver esse erro, eu nem sabia que esse "XUA" existia. Deve ser o servidor q está servindo meu site com esse header, por que eu não coloquei.

Comment: @JoãoMarcos Eu acredito :) ... Então, não tem nenhum outro .htaccess em outra pasta? Você usa Apache ou Ngnix?